# Linking to an ajax div

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

Okay guys hopefully I can explain this effectively, so here goes.

I have a unordered list where each list item loads html pages into a div on click via jquery on my "Services" page.

Basically on the front page I have a couple links, when one is clicked, I need it to go to the "Services" and see the appropriate html page in the div.

Here's kinda how the code is:

Services Page:

```
<ul id="service-nav">

            <li><a id="interlocking" href="#">Interlocking</a></li>
            <li><a id="pool-backfill" href="#">Pool Backfill</a></li>
            <li><a id="poured-concrete" href="#">Poured Concrete</a></li>
            <li><a id="parging" href="#">Parging</a></li>
            <li><a id="custom-land" href="#">Custom Landscaping</a></li>
            <li><a id="snow-rem" href="#">Snow Removal</a></li>
            <li><a id="excavation" href="#">Excavation</a></li></ul>
      </ul>

    <div id="right-area"> <!-- This is where we load the relevant html's -->
    </div>
```

Front Page:

```
        <ul>
            <li><a href="services.php?token=interlocking">Interlocking</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php?token=pool-backfill">Pool Backfill</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php?token=poured-concrete">Poured Concrete</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And here is my jQuery for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function(){ 
        var token = window.location.toString().split("=")[1]; 

        $("#" + token).click(); 

        });​


    $('#interlocking').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/interlocking.php', function() {
        });
    });

    $('#pool-backfill').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/pool-backfill.php', function() {
        });
    });

    $('#poured-concrete').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/poured-concrete.php', function() {
        });
    });

    $('#parging').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/parging.php', function() {
        });
    });

    $('#custom-land').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/custom-landscaping.php', function() {
        });
    });

    $('#excavation').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/excavation.php', function() {
        });
    });

    $('#snow-rem').click(function() {
        $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/snow-removal.php', function() {
        });
    });







});

</script>
```

Comment: where is the relevant HTML located? If you can show that, we can figure out how to access it with an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, suppose we want to show the interlocking page, so your front page should be like this:

1.

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="services.php?token=Interlocking">Interlocking</a></li>
    </ul>
```

2.In your service page, the jquery code should be:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){ 




    $('#interlocking').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/interlocking.php', function() {
    });
});

$('#pool-backfill').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/pool-backfill.php', function() {
    });
});

$('#poured-concrete').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/poured-concrete.php', function() {
    });
});

$('#parging').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/parging.php', function() {
    });
});

$('#custom-land').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/custom-landscaping.php', function() {
    });
});

$('#excavation').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/excavation.php', function() {
    });
});

$('#snow-rem').click(function() {
    $('#right-area').load('http://romanstonedesigns.com/new/services/snow-removal.php', function() {
    });
});

    var token = window.location.toString().split("=")[1]; 
    $("#" + token).click(); 

    });
```

Bye!

Comment: could you give me an example of the jquery function would look like?

Comment: you have to put the id's on your service page, as tokens on the front-page, and voilá!

Comment: okay it doesnt seem to work, im prolly doing something wrong, i have updated the post

Comment: make an alert call after the token declaration, like that: alert(token), i think the problem can be there...

Comment: the alert comes up fine, for some reason the function tag wrapping it makes it not work

Comment: Ok i see whats happening, Im going to change my code, so you can fix yours, it was about to change the orders of commands.